# MongoDB Aggregation - Count, lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm new to MongoDB. I'm was trying to do an assignment using Aggregation.

**Questions:**

1. How to count attendees participating in different events?
2. In those attendees, who got the COVID19 vaccine before?
3. In addition to events, they offer COVID19 vaccines during the events. How many people want the COVID19 vaccine.

My data of events schema:

```
[{
  "_id": "87154163-d277-42cc-912c-e316dac5140d",
  "eventType": "A",
  "date": {
    "$date": "2021-09-04T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "location": "Japan",
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": "0b168c44-4f38-4f86-8ee6-e077333aca95",
  "eventType": "B",
  "date": {
    "$date": "2021-09-08T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "location": "Korea",
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": "91205d34-4480-4e4e-bdf7-fe66e46922b0",
  "eventType": "C",
  "date": {
    "$date": "2021-10-09T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "location": "United States",
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": "d4d81da6-b453-4a31-999f-a2ea04848ee9",
  "eventType": "D",
  "date": {
    "$date": "2021-10-17T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "location": "India",
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": "b1606383-0382-4985-bbb1-44f2ef35efbe",
  "eventType": "E",
  "date": {
    "$date": "2021-10-17T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "location": "Germany",
  "__v": 0
}]
```

My data of attendees schema:

```
[{
  "_id": "4d4649f0-27c7-11ec-a6de-c566600748e5",
  "firstName": "Abigail",
  "lastName": "Ava",
  "zipCode": 12345,
  "COVID19": {
    "WantedCOVIDvaccine": "no",          // WantedVaccine
    "ReceivedVaccine": "no"              // Vaccinated
  },
  "event": ["A", "B"],
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": "8776ae80-27c7-11ec-a6de-c566600748e5",
  "firstName": "Alexandra",
  "lastName": "Claire",
  "zipCode": 45678,
  "COVID19": {
    "WantedCOVIDvaccine": "no",
    "ReceivedVaccine": "yes"
  },
  "event": ["A"],
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": "963eb570-27c7-11ec-a6de-c566600748e5",
  "firstName": "Lauren",
  "lastName": "Rachel",
  "zipCode": 54321,
  "COVID19": {
    "WantedCOVIDvaccine": "yes",
    "ReceivedVaccine": "no"
  },
  "event": ["C", "D"],
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": "cc8f6ed0-27c7-11ec-a6de-c566600748e5",
  "firstName": "Michelle",
  "lastName": "Tracey",
  "zipCode": 12345,
  "COVID19": {
    "WantedCOVIDvaccine": "no",
    "ReceivedVaccine": "yes"
  },
  "event": ["A", "C", "D"],
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": "e9a124f0-27c7-11ec-a6de-c566600748e5",
  "firstName": "Theresa",
  "lastName": "Sue",
  "zipCode": 91586,
  "COVID19": {
    "WantedCOVIDvaccine": "no",
    "ReceivedVaccine": "yes"
  },
  "event": ["B", "C", "D"],
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": "09969a10-27c8-11ec-a6de-c566600748e5",
  "firstName": "Christopher",
  "lastName": "Penelope",
  "zipCode": 12362,
  "COVID19": {
    "WantedCOVIDvaccine": "no",
    "ReceivedVaccine": "yes"
  },
  "event": ["A", "D"],
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": "610ff160-27c8-11ec-a6de-c566600748e5",
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Diane",
  "zipCode": 45678,
  "COVID19": {
    "WantedCOVIDvaccine": "yes",
    "ReceivedVaccine": "yes"
  },
  "event": ["A", "C"],
  "__v": 0
}]
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "AttendeesEvents": {
      "A": 5,
      "B": 2,
      "C": 4,
      "D": 4,
      "E": 0
    },
    "Vaccinated": {
      "A": 4,
      "B": 1,
      "C": 3,
      "D": 3,
      "E": 0
    },
    "WantedVaccine": {
      "A": 4,
      "B": 1,
      "C": 3,
      "D": 3,
      "E": 0
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69906107/2282634

Comment: This helped me a little bit. Thank you so much.