# MongoDB group by elements in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection that looks like this:

```json
{
  "id": "id1",
  "tags": ['a', 'b']
},
{
  "id": "id2",
  "tags": ['b', 'c']
},
{
  "id": "id3",
  "tags": ['a', 'c']
}
```

How can I make a query that groups by every element in the "tags" array, so the result looks like this?:

```
{'a': 2},
{'b': 2},
{'c': 2}
```

(where 2 is the number of times it appears, the count).
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First `$unwind` the array to deconstruct an access like objects.
- Then `$group` by `tags` and `$sum` 1 to get the total.
- And last use `$replaceRoot` with `$arrayToObject` to get the desired output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$tags"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$tags",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": [
          [
            {
              "k": "$_id",
              "v": "$count"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GmF7y9zr0en)

As an adittion, if you want to get sorted values (a, b, c...) you can add `$sort` stage like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CTFOGLCJBNw)

Comment: Thank you very much for your full answer! This helped me a lot